# Curve integral and normal vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Problem:

$$\int_{C}F\cdot dr$$

$$F=(y,2x-z,3x+2y)$$

C is the circle in the plane $x=z$ centered in (0,0,0) with a radius of 1. C is traversed once in the direction so that $x$ decrease when passing the point (0,1,0).

From the solution sheet:

$$\nabla xF =(3,-3,1)$$

(Stokes)

$$\int_{C}F\cdot dr=\iint(3,-3,1)\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1,0,1)dS=...$$

Question 1: What I don't understand is how they arrive at the normal vector $(-1,0,1)$? The other problems I've solved always use a $(0,0,1)$-type vector. Is this visualized somehow through drawing the circle?

Question 2: When do I need to take into consideration (and divide by) the vector length (in this case $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$)? Or is that always done, only that in the $(0,0,1)$-case the length is 1?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Usually the direction of the normal vector in Stokes theorem is given by the right hand rule. You curl your fingers in the direction the path is being traversed and your thumb points in the direction of the normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(-1,0,1) is the normal vector for the plane x=z (the equation can be written as -1*x + 0*y +1*z =0).  You are correct about question 2, you always want the unit normal vector.

Comment: Wow, it was that simple. It also aligns well with another question I had problems with. Thank you a thousand times.

Comment: Follow up: Why would I select (-1,0,1) instead of (1,0,-1)?

Comment: See Spencer's comment - it has to do with the orientation of C.

Comment: Ah yes of course. Thanks again @mathematician.